# What is the best approach? Binary Search Tree : Lowest Common Ancestor using only if statements

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have solved the problem with only if statements. It can be solved in various other ways. I have just started programming, so I could not think of using any other data structure for solving this.

**My QUESTION :**
How to choose the best approach among various ways? And what are the advantages/disadvantages of this best approach compared to my direct naive approach.

Not only for this problem, in general. How to arrive at the possible approach for any problem?

**Problem Statement**

You are given pointer to the root of the binary search tree and two values v1 and v2. You need to return the lowest common ancestor (LCA) of v1 and v2 in the binary search tree. You only need to complete the function.

[image]

**My code:**

```
static Node lca(Node root,int v1,int v2)
 { 
    Node r = root;
    if( r == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(r.data == v1 || r.data == v2){
        return r;
    }
    else if(r.data > v1 && r.data < v2){
        return r;
    }
    else if(r.data > v2 && r.data < v1){
        return r;
    }
    else if( r.data > v1 && r.data > v2){
        lca(r.left, v1, v2);
    }
    else if( r.data < v1 && r.data < v2){
        lca(r.right, v1, v2);
    }
   return null;
 }
```

Problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-lowest-common-ancestor

Comment: Apart from two `return`s missing from `lca(r.left...)` and `lca(r.right...)`, the solution seems to be correct. As you correctly identified, the LCA will be the number that is greater than `v1` but less than `v2` (or vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's how I would approach the problem. This relies on the fact that you're dealing with a binary search tree.

For any given node, it can be the LCA if and only if `min(v1, v2)` is in its *left* subtree, and `max(v1, v2)` is in its *right* subtree. If this isn't true, then the current node clearly can't be an ancestor, because either v1 or v2 cannot be a descendant. Continue traversing down the tree until the LCA condition is met.

Your solution is correct and you have the intuition down, but we can strip out the recursion and simply perform an iterative BST find, which also implicitly contains your `if` checks.

In terms of advantages, you're really just wasting the implicit recursion call stack space, of which it also has to unwind at the end. Both of our implementations run in `O(log N)`, since you'll examine `log N - 1` nodes in the worst case, where `v1` and `v2` are direct siblings at the bottom of a full and complete tree.

**Implementation**

1. Swap `v1` and `v2` if `v1 < v2` (remove the need for `min` and `max` checks). This implicitly contains *both* of your `if` checks for `v1 < root < v2` and `v2 < root < v1`.
2. While the current node's value is smaller than `v1` (`v1` is in the right subtree) or greater than `v2`, move *towards* `v1` or `v2`. This replaces your recursive traversal.

Here's a quick implementation that I checked:

```
static Node lca(Node root, int v1, int v2)    {
    if (root == null) return null;
    if (v1 > v2) {          
        int temp = v2;
        v2 = v1;
        v1 = temp;
    }
    while (root.data < v1 || root.data > v2) {
        if (root.data < v1)      root = root.right;
        else if (root.data > v2) root = root.left;
    }       
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and a better code.

Comment: Maybe accept the answer (check mark) if you're satisfied? Let me know if there's anything I can clarify, thanks!

Comment: I want to accept both the answers, but I don't think that's possible. That's why I upvoted both the answers.

Comment: I submitted similar code in hacker rank with do while loop, failing for one case.

Answer (score 1):

Better approaches are normally have:

1. Better time or/and space complexity.
2. Readable code.
3. Manages edge cases better.
4. I believe that it will produce smaller code most of the times.

If we look at your code :

```
 static Node lca(Node root,int v1,int v2)
 { 
     Node r = root;
    if( r == null){
       return null;
    }
    else if(r.data == v1 || r.data == v2){
       return r;
    }
    else if(r.data > v1 && r.data < v2){
       return r;
    }
    else if(r.data > v2 && r.data < v1){
      return r;
    }
    else if( r.data > v1 && r.data > v2){
       lca(r.left, v1, v2);
    }
    else if( r.data < v1 && r.data < v2){
      lca(r.right, v1, v2);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Time or Space complexity wise your code is also efficient, I want to touch few point on readability.

1. All your `if` statements return something, so actually don't need to   write `else if`, just `if` will be enough.
2. when `root` is `null` or `v1` or `v2`, you are returning `root` only, so you can combine first two conditions.

   **NOTE:** If you are worried about your elements not present in the tree, you can always check for their existence before call this function. I like it this way, you might want to add your other extra conditions and `return null` if you want to.

   ```
    static Node lca(Node root,int v1,int v2)
    { 
       Node r = root;
      if( r == null || r == v1 || r == v2){
          return root;
      }

     if( r.data > v1 && r.data > v2){
         lca(r.left, v1, v2);
     }

     if( r.data < v1 && r.data < v2){
         lca(r.right, v1, v2);
     }
     return root; // instead of checking the other two conditions, you can directly return the root.
   }
   ```

Comment: I would still argue that a recursive implementation is unnecessary in this case, when the traversal is so straightforward (binary search). I do agree with your points on simplifying the return value calculations.

Comment: @AaronZou you are right, but it depends a lot on personal choice and code style. As the OP just started coding, I thought recursion would be a simple and more intuitive way to solve the problem.

Comment: @karthik  Thank you for pointing out my mistakes  and for the better approach explanation.